# Check from which Class the object has been created

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, class

I was searching for a common question but couldn't find any solution even after googling. Maybe I am searching wrong?

Is it possible to know from which class the object has been created?
For Example: In Visual Basic Code:

I have a class,

```
Public Class dummyA

End Class
```

I have another class,

```
Public Class dummyMain
    Dim dmmA As New dummyA
End Class
```

Can I check in `dummyA`, if the object has been created from dummyMain?

Answer with c# or VB.Net would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to have an overloaded constructor and pass the owner into it.

```cs
public class DummyA
{
    public DummyA(object owner)
    {
       var createdByDummyMain = owner is DummyMain;
    }
}
```

and then do

```cs
public class DummyMain
{
    public DummyMain()
    {
        var dmmA = new DummyA(this);
    }
}
```

There is also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/caller-information) but it won't give you exactly what you want. There are other proposals too that deal with `StackFrame` but it isn't reliable due to JIT optimizations.

Comment: And note that it will seldom be a good idea for the type of `owner` to be `Object`, especially outside of debugging scenarios.  In most cases, the type should be something more specific that will provide whatever facility you want the class to use (most likely some kind of `Interface`).